# In a java developed REST based app java architecture, should I split an implementation for requests/validations and one for domain?

Tags: java, rest

In the past lets say I have a domain model of `Bike`, so I'd make an interface called `Bike`, and in the past I'd create a implementation of that.  And in that implementation, I'd cram validation, JSON rules, database mapping annotations, etc.
This seems to make the system ugly and brittle. So many gyrations to map and display and transform.

I'm wondering (as I experiment) if I should create one implementation that just takes inputs and validates the data, and from it creates an instance of the model for use deeper inside the code after some transformations.
So:

```
(Type)Bike -> BikeWeb, BikeModel
```

However when I do that it seems that I lose the whole point of the json transformations, and add complexity with Interface hell. Because what I see happening is

```
(Type)Bike -> (Types) BikeWeb, BikeModel -> BikeWebImpl, BikeModelImpl
```

...times 1000

I'm asking is the design pattern I'm describing one that is typical with some debate on which way to go, the actual pattern I should be using, or i'm out of my gourd.

It seems every REST solution in the java world has this dilemma for me, so maybe should be using another solution, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I've no idea why you need interface along with the implementation for model. Why don't you use just `Bike` class to represent model?

It seems that what you're looking for is a DTO pattern. A DTO object is represents an instance of payload that is sent via request or response. Such object can be validated in terms of JSON syntax, and *some* values - I mean that some fields may be set to hold value between 0 and 10. Such validation can be done at this level. The second kind of object is the model itself. This way there are two classes only `BikeDTO` and `Bike`. Please have a look at this [article](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/understanding-spring-web-application-architecture-the-classic-way/). It might shed a light on your doubts.